# C++ Pass any container to function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to find a way to iterate through any STL container. Currently I have this:

```
std::string range(std::vector<int>& args)
{
    for (auto it : args)
        // do something
}
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to pass any type of STL container with any type to the function instead of `std::vector<int>& args`. How can I do this?

Comment: `template<typename Container> std::string range(Container& args)`

Comment: Read up on [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: sigh, another duplicate.

Comment: almost everything you want to do on a range of items in a template is already covered in the `<algorithm>` header. Here's a link to some information on it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: Pass begin- and end-iterators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use templates.

```
template<typename Container>
std::string range(Container& args)
{
   for (auto it : args)
      // do something
}
```

Probably with overloading for special types (`std::map` for example).

Comment: Can you pass `set` to that function? I think you need to make that parameter `const`.

Comment: @BЈовић probably, but I just copied signature in OP question.

Comment: @ForEveR Why do I see many recommendations of templates being used to pass around containers instead of using references or pointers? As with your answer, they don't explain why..

Answer (score 2):

Consider that everything in algorithm does this.

You can call `copy`, for example, on a `list` and on `vector`.

It seems like following that pattern is your best bet:

```
template<class InputIterator>
std::string range(InputIterator first, const InputIterator last)
{
    while(first != last){
        // do something
        ++first;
    }
}
```

All that to say it depends on what you're going for but it's very likely that you can use a lambda and one of the `find` algorithms or `accumulate` to accomplish whatever you're doing in `range`.